# Import script in the same level but also from top level

Tags: python, path, python-import, directory-structure

I have the following folder structure:

```
top folder

 - final_program.py
 - scripts
   - __init__.py
   - extract.py
   - estimations.py
   - calculate_all.py
```

The final_program.py runs a function in calculate_all.py. So, I have this:

```
from scripts.calculate_all import get_info
```

However, the calculate_all.py script uses both extract.py and estimations.py scripts. So, in calculate_all.py, I have this:

```
import scripts.estimations
import scripts.extract
```

When running final_program.py directly, I run into no errors. Great. However, I'd like to also be able to run calculate_all.py directly. When I try to, I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.estimations'

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

- Added `__init__.py` in top-level
- In calculate_all:

```py
from . import estimations
from . import extract
```

- In final_program:

```py
import scripts.calculate_all
import scripts.extract
```

Run the python files using the `-m` flag (run the module as a script).

For final_program: `python -m final_program`
For calculate_all: `python -m scripts.calculate_all`

Comment: I'm getting a SyntaxError when doing this. I also tried 'from . import extract' but then I get an ImportError: cannot import name 'extract'.

Comment: I got that same error, but after some experimentation I got something to work (answer edited). Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: In scripts? Do you mean the __init__.py file in the scripts folder, or something else?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo - I meant in `final_program`.

Answer (score 0):

use in `calculate_all.py`

```
import .estimations
import .extract
```